# How to set up python debugger for VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I used the same settings on Windows and on my corporate Mac, but on Mac it seems it's not working properly?

I get the error:

> The debug type is not recognized. Make sure that you have a corresponding debug extension installed and that it is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not recognizing `"type": "python"` as a debug configuration.

You need to install the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) on your Mac copy of VS Code. Then, follow the instructions from the VS Code docs on setting it up [Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) again for that workspace:

> The Python extension supports debugging of a number of types of Python applications.
>   ...
>
> ### Initialize configurations
>
> A configuration drives VS Code's behavior during a debugging session.
>   Configurations are defined in a `launch.json` file that's stored in a
>   `.vscode` folder in your workspace.

From the looks of your *launch.json* file, you should be good to go once the extension is installed. If it still can't recognize `"type": "python",` as a debug configuration, try reloading VS Code and/or making sure the extension is enabled for the current workspace:

[image]